# How to remove a word from the url in codeigniter without using .htaccess

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a site with urls:

```
http://example.com/controller-name/page/about
http://example.com/controller-name/page/contactus
http://example.com/controller-name/page/services
```

But I need the urls like:

```
http://example.com/controller-name/about
http://example.com/controller-name/contactus
http://example.com/controller-name/services
```

How to do this in `Codeigniter`?

Comment: re-define your routes?

Comment: Why did you make this page function anyway?

Comment: I have used a controller and inside that the method called `page` and the `about`,`contactus` and `services` are the parameters for a variable $sub. for example `class Main extends CI_Controller { public function page($sub="none"){if($sub!='none'){ $this->load->view('innerpage', $data);} else {$this->load->view('sub-detail', $data);}`

Answer (score 0):

You can configure URI Routing to achieve this. Refer [Codeigniter documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html) for a detailed explanation.

You can map a URL string to its corresponding controller class/method

Answer (score 0):

Hope this one help you.

```
$route['controller-name/(:any)'] = "controller-name/your method";
```